# safari iOS - disable hiding address bar on input focus

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

Is there a way to disable the scrolling that happens when tapping an input box in safari iOS? My site is not well suited to the scrolling that happens and actually makes the site less user friendly.

I've tried using:

```
$('input,select,textarea').bind('focus',function(e) { 
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

But it only forces safari to scroll to the top of my document, which means that the address bar is still "hidden." I just don't understand why if window.scrollTo(0, 1) is supposed to "hide" the address bar, why doesn't window.scrollTo(0, 0) reveal it?

Similarly, is there a way to prevent safari from scrolling the document when textarea is scrolled over/swiped across? Currently, if I scroll down the page and happen to scroll across a textarea field, it scrolls the whole page. Actually, on second look, it seems to do this on input fields as well sometimes.

Comment: I'm using iscroll if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck preventing address bar from appearing when input is focused with this code. This is spammy, but it's a fairly brief burst and seems to do the trick.

```
var top = 1; // or your input box position
var spamStop = (new Date()).getTime() + 10; 
var scrollSpam_id = setInterval(function () {
    var t = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (t > spamStop) {
      clearInterval(scrollSpam_id);
    } else {
      window.scrollTo(0, top);
    }
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old question, but it might help someone later :)

This is what i do, so that the address bar won't be shown on input focus, while always hiding the address bar on detection of any scroll event.

```
var inputInFocus=false;
$('input').focus(function(){
  inputInFocus=true;
});
$('input').blur(function(){
  inputInFocus=false;
  setTimeout("$(document).scrollTop(0);",0);
});
/*detect any scroll function and hide address bar*/
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(!inputInFocus){
setTimeout("$(document).scrollTop(0);",200);
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my opinion. It scrolls up after every scroll event, so blocking natural scrolling on the site. Did you mean to check for "if(inputFocus)" just after the comment?